# How to search over Alias having index with different mappings using nest.net

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have created 2 index say

```
1. 

PUT /my_blog
{
  "mappings":{
    "post":{
      "properties":{
        "user_id":{
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "post_text":{
          "type": "text",
           "fielddata":true
        },
        "post_date":{
          "type": "date"
          , "format": "YYYY-MM-DD"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

2. 

PUT /eventlog-2014-08-01
{
  "mappings":{
    "event":{
      "properties":{
        "error":{
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is to create a single query over these 2 indices so that I can find certain text in my "post_text" of (my_blog index) and "error" of (eventlog-2014-08-01) index.

I could achieve this by creating a single Alias for these 2 indices like this

```
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "my_blog",
        "alias": "eventlog"
      }
    }
  ]
}

 POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "eventlog-2014-08-02",
        "alias": "eventlog"
      }
    }
  ]
}

GET eventlog/_search
{
  "query":{
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Martijn another mind",
      "fields": ["error","post_text"]
    }
  }
}
```

and then creating a multimatch query like this 
but I want to achieve this using nest.net which I could not achieve.

Is there any way by which I can achieve this using nest.net?

Is there any other way using nest.net to achieve my result.

As I am beginner any help with code snippet will be more helpful to understand.

Comment: Which part is making trouble when you try to recreate behaviour with NEST?

Comment: I am facing issue to write a search query using NEST over my alias to search across the multiple indexes which are bound to the alias.

Answer (score 0):

You could write following query

```
var searchResponse = await client.SearchAsync<dynamic>(s => s
    .Index("eventlog")
    .Query(q => q.MultiMatch(mm => mm
        .Query("Martijn another mind")
        .Fields(fields => fields.Fields("error", "post_text")))));
```

this

```
foreach (var hit in searchResponse.Hits)
{
    var source = hit.Source as IDictionary<string,object>;
    if (source == null) continue;

    source.TryGetValue("error", out var error);
    source.TryGetValue("post_text", out var post_text);
    System.Console.WriteLine($"{hit.Index}: error: {error} post_text: {post_text}");
}
```

will print

```
eventlog-2014-08-02: error: mind post_text: 
my_blog: error:  post_text: another
```

My test documents:

```
PUT my_blog/_doc/1
{
  "post_text": "another"
}

PUT eventlog-2014-08-02/_doc/1
{
  "error": "mind"
}
```

Tested with elasticsearch 7.2.0 and NEST 7.2.1.

Hope that helps.